# Disable focus on tabstop when TextBox is readonly

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpf-style

When a TextBox is in readonly and on tabbing i want to disable the focus border of the textbox, i wanted to do this in Style of textbox.Can any one help me to achieve this?

Updated the content:

Screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place a condition like the below in your textbox style

```
<MultiTrigger>
    <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
        <Condition Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True"></Condition>
        <Condition Property="IsFocused" Value="True"></Condition>               </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
    <MultiTrigger.Setters>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{#7B2F81}"></Setter>
    </MultiTrigger.Setters>
```

Comment: Arushi Agrawal please check my style in your post.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="FocusVisualStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Control}">
        <Setter Property="Control.Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Control}">
                    <Border SnapsToDevicePixels="True" 
                            CornerRadius="0" 
                            BorderThickness="2"
                            BorderBrush="#7B2F81" />
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Pink" />

        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource FocusVisualStyle}" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <TextBox Text="TestText" 
             IsReadOnly="True"
             HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
             VerticalAlignment="Center" />
</Grid>
```

If `TextBox.IsReadOnly == True` then set [`FocusVisualStyle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613567(v=vs.110).aspx) in StyleTrigger. Visual behavior of Focus you can customize in `FocusVisualStyle`.

Comment: when the textbox is readonly and then we focus the textbox on pressing tab I have to set "FocusVisual" border to "collapsed", but when user tries focus the text box then the "FocusVisual" should be enabled.

Comment: @user2408987: I do not understand what you want, you can show examples, diagrams?

Comment: Modified the original content please check.